# Execute a batch script in Maven aggregator once per module

Tags: windows, maven, batch-file, aggregator

I am using the [exec-maven-plugin](http://www.mojohaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/) to execute a batch command for specific modules.

The entire product we build consists of several of these modules and i am using an aggregator to build all the necessary modules at once.
We are trying to simplify the process of executing the batch scripts once per module, because the execution script is almost identical for every plugin and simply requires the current plugin path.

Is it somehow possible to execute a batch script from within the aggregator, but once for every module?
Let's say my aggregator looks like this:

```
<project xmlns= ...>
....    
    <modules>
        <module>../ModuleA</module>
        <module>../ModuleB</module>
        ...
        <module>../ModuleZ</module>
    </modules>
</project>
```

Would it be possible to execute a batch command such as `myBatch.bat -i ..\ModuleX` *from within the aggregator*, where `ModuleX` denotes the most recently built module?

It is important that the execution of the batch script is a "post-build" step executed after the module was successfully built. 
The executed script is an external tool used to obfuscate the .jar files.

I am thankful for any small working examples as well as hints on where to find more information on this.

Comment: Can you describe what you are doing in this step with batch command?

Comment: The batch command is used to obfuscate the generated .jar files. I edited my question accordingly.